# casting char * to char[]

Tags: c, casting, char

Example:

```
char str[10];

gets(str);
str = (char[10]) strtok(str, " "); // type error here
```

Since `strtok()` returns a `char *`, I get an type error without that casting. With it I get the following:

```
error: cast specifies array type
```

What is the best to fix this code?

Comment: `char* ptr = strtok(str," ");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh man, be careful with that `gets()`! [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2843073/557306)

---

You can't assign to arrays (in other words, use them as lvalues).

```
char *p = "string";
char array[10];
array = p; /* invalid */
```

Apart from that, you're not using `strtok()` correctly. The pointer returned points to the subsequent token, so you might want to create a separate char pointer to store it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be assigning the result of strtok into a separate char* variable. You can't assign it back into str.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be assigning the reult of `strtok()` back to your `str` variable in the first place.  Use a separate variable instead, eg:

```
char str[10]; 
gets(str); 
char *token = strtok(str, " ");
//use token as needed...
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign anything to an array. Even this simplistic program will fail:

```
char *foo(void) { }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char a[1];

        a = foo();

        return 0;
}
```

As indeed it does:

```
$ make fail
cc     fail.c   -o fail
fail.c: In function ‘main’:
fail.c:7:4: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[1]’ from type ‘char *’
make: *** [fail] Error 1
```

Either re-define `str` as `char *str` or figure out some other way to re-write your program to not attempt to assign to an array. (What does the surrounding code look like? The code you've pasted doesn't really make sense anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

You can get parameter before calling your function:

```
char mystr[] = "192.168.0.2";
split_ip(myster[]);
char * split_ip( char  ip_address[]){

unsigned short counter = 0;
char *token;
token = strtok (ip_address,".");
while (token != '\0')
{

printf("%s\n",token);

token = strtok ('\0', ".");
}
}// end of function def
```