# C - Metric conversion strings

Tags: c

I'm trying to be able to allow my program to recognize what is being entered in to the token string and compare it to the metric measurement so I can make multiple conversions like kilo, centi, etc. The problem im running into is I cant get the program to recognize milli right now.

Also note that there is a function for converting english into pig latin so ignore some of the pig latin variables

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int command = 0, //Pig latin ints
    count = 0;
double tokenNum;
char name[50];
char *tokens[10];
char *englishLength[] = {"feet"};
char *metricLength[] = {"meter", "milli", "centi", "deci", "deka", "hecto", "kilo"};    
char sentence_ar[100], //Pig latin chars
     *array_of_pointers_to_strings[50],
     new_string1[50] = {'\0'},
     new_string2[50] = {'\0'};




printf ("Enter conversion in the following format\n -- How many meters are in X feet --:\n ");
            fflush (stdin);
            gets(name);

            printf ("Original name: %s\n", name);
            tokens[0] = strtok (name, " ");

            printf ("Token[0]: %s\n", tokens[0]);

            i++;

            while ((tokens[i] = strtok (NULL, " ")) != NULL)
            {
                printf ("Token[%d]: %s\n", i, tokens[i]);
                i++;
            }

            tokenNum = atof (tokens[5]);

            printf("%d\n", tokenNum);

            while (j < 1)
                {
                    if (strcmp(tokens[6],metricLength[0])==0);
                    {
                        // feet to meters
                        double result;

                        result = tokenNum * 0.3048;
                        j++;
                        printf("Feet to Meters %f\n", result);
                        // if you enter How many meters are in 5 feet, ANSWER: 1.524
                    }
                    // when token[6] = milli
                    if (strcmp(tokens[6],metricLength[1])==0)
                    {
                        //feet to millimeters
                        double result;

                        result = tokenNum * 304.8;
                        j++;
                        printf("Feet to Milli %f\n", result);
                        // if you enter How many milli are in 5 feet, ANSWER: 1524
                    }
            }
```

Comment: You meant "milli" instead of "pilli" I guess

Comment: yeah my mistake, that was from last night when I was trying to get the program to recognize the p instead of m. i'm fairly new at programming and it didnt work haha

Comment: Happens! :) ... Doesn't it work even after the change?

Comment: You have the potential to overflow your array here: `while ((tokens[i] = strtok (NULL, " ")) != NULL)` -  no bounds checking on `i`.

Comment: You could also associate your array of measurement strings with a conversion multiplier, so that you don't have to create a separate `if` block for each type.

Comment: well it converts feet to meters even if i enter milli or before "pilli" lol.

Comment: @JoeBray: That's because there's a semicolon (`;`) after your first `if` statement - the feet to meters code will always be executed if you get into the `while` loop.

Comment: Someone has to say it: don't use `gets`, don't even think about it.

Comment: @muistooshort just bet me too it, use `fgets(string, size, stdin)` instead.

Comment: @AusCBloke i'm in begining computer science (cpts 121), could you show me an example possibly?

Comment: The constant indexes 5 and 6 are suspicious (as in `tokens[5]` and `tokens[6]`).  What are you typing before your length to make the number appear at index 5 and the units at index 6?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think he's wanting it to be: "How many meters are in VALUE UNITS"

Comment: Yeah i want "How many METRIC UNIT are in VALUE ENGLISH UNIT. Once I can figure that out than I can reverse it and do it for volume and weight as well later.

Comment: `stdin` is the standard input, that's what `scanf` and `gets` read from.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few observations which you can use (This is more of a compilation of the comments above):
1. Don't use `fflush(stdin)`. [`fflush` is for output stream only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).
2. Don't use `gets`.  [Its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843073/warninggets-function-is-dangerous). Use `fgets` as suggested.
3. Add bound checks to your array. In `while ((tokens[i] = strtok (NULL, " ")) != NULL)`, you should check for the value of `i` so that is does not exceed the allocated array size of `tokens`
4. In the statement `if (strcmp(tokens[6],metricLength[0])==0);`, the semicolon makes this condition result in empty body. I think adding the semicolon was not intended so get rid of it.
5. As per your input requirement, you are checking the wrong token. If your input requires "How many METRIC_UNIT are in VALUE ENGLISH_UNIT", then you should compare the third token i.e. `tokens[2]`. If may be a good idea to validate the input as well.
6. Crank up the warnings on your compiler to the max & fix them all! Its a good practice.
Hope this helps!