# c : gets() and fputs() are dangerous functions?

Tags: c, gcc, gets, fputs

In the computer lab at school we wrote a program using `fputs` and the compiler returned an error `gets is a dangerous function to use` and a similar error for `fputs`
but at home when i type in this bit of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char name[20];
    fp = fopen("name.txt","w");
    gets(name);

    fputs(name,fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

i get no errors what so ever. The one at school was similar to this one, just a bit lengthy and having more variables.
I use codeblocks at home and the default gcc provided with fedora at school.
Could it be a problem with the compiler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843073/warninggets-function-is-dangerous

Comment: Thats why home is better than school :)

Comment: The school's lab environment may have been configured so that GCC compiles at a higher warning level than your setup. In any case, it's best to heed the warning.

Comment: Twxo important rules of thumb when you are a newbie: trust the compiler (it is very rarely wrong!) and ask it to give all warnings (with `gcc -Wall`). Most real programmers improve their code till no warnings is given.

Comment: Sounds like someone is playing god on the school machines.  It would be better if they tried to educate instead.  It is better to teach you how to fish than to just give you a fish.  (Better to teach you why they think these things are bad than to prevent you from learning outright).

Comment: FYI **`gets` is so dangerous that it has been removed from the latest C standard**. Never, never, never use it. It is a relic from the past of the first C on Unix in the 1970-s. But `puts`  is safe to use.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I actually go _further_ than that and use `gcc -Wall -Wextra` since I found out `gcc` was a pathological liar about the definition of "all" :-)

Comment: See for yourself, After compiling run `echo {0..100} | tr -d ' './a.out`

Answer (score 2):

With `gets` you need exactly know how many characters you will read and accordingly use a large enough buffer. If you use a buffer which is lesser than the contents of the file you read, you end up writing beyond the bounds of your allocated buffer and this results in an **Undefined Behavior** and an Invalid program.

Instead you should use `fgets` which allows you to specify how much data to read.

You don't get any errors because most likely your allocated buffer `name` is big enough to hold the contents of you file `name.txt` but if it was not then its a problem and hence the compiler issues the warning.

Answer (score 1):

`gets` is certainly dangerous since there's no way to prevent buffer overflow.

For example, if your user entered 150 characters, that would almost certainly cause problems for your program. Use of `scanf` with an unbounded `"%s"` format specifier should also be avoided for input you have no control over.

However, the use of `gets` should *not* be an error since it complies with the standard. At *most,* it should be a warning (unless you, as the developer, configures something like "treat warnings as errors").

`fputs` is fine, not dangerous at all.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921) for a robust user input function, using `fgets`, which can be used to prevent buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

It would just be the different settings of the different compilers. Maybe the compiler that Codeblocks uses isn't as verbose or has warnings turned off.

Regardless of the compiler they are dangerous functions to use as they have no checks for buffer overflow. Use fgets or fputs instead.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have all addressed `gets`, which is really and truly dangerous.

But the question also mentioned `fputs`.  The `fputs` function is perfectly safe; it does not have these kinds of security concerns.

I believe the OP was probably mistaken in suggesting that the compiler had warned about `fputs`.

Answer (score 0):

As for problems, there isn't any problem with any of the compilers. If you look at the link provided by Timothy Jones, you would understand why this warning is issued. As for different versions of compiler, compilers are configured differently to issue different levels of warning.