# Arrays Stack Overflow

Tags: c

```
    #include
    int main(void)
    {
        char str[100]="88888888888888";
        char t[20]="";
        gets(t);
        puts(str);
        puts(t);
        return 0;
    }
```

[image]

The first line

```
555555555555555555555555555555555
```

is put in.

Why `str` is `55555555555`? Why `str` isn't `88888888888888888` or `55555555555588888`?

Comment: Don't use `gets`. http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-56.html

Comment: please search SO before posting. E.g there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843073/warninggets-function-is-dangerous

Comment: `gets` is removed from POSIX and C11 for good reasons.

Answer (score 6):

You overriden the `t` buffer, and reached the `str` buffer, where the rest of the input, and the null terminator was set. And `puts` prints only until the null terminator.

Pretty much looks like that:

```
[ t (20)             ][str(100)                                 ]
 55555555555555555555  5555555555555\0
```

Note that although `t` is declared as `char[20]`, when you print it you get the full input (longer than 20), since `puts` stops at the null terminator (again).

BTW, this is a buffer overflow, not a stackoverflow, but stack overflow is possible on this codeas well.

Answer (score 1):

As Binyamin said it is caused by the overflow you trigger because of the input string being too long. However it is a bit random thing - sometimes the two memory allocations will happen just next to each other and the string will extend to the neighbouring variables, sometimes it might not happen.

I advise you to place guard conditions for such kind of overflows.

If you see in the `gets` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/gets/):

> Notice that gets does not behave exactly as fgets does with stdin as
>   argument: First, the ending newline character is not included with
>   gets while with fgets it is. And second, gets does not let you specify
>   a limit on how many characters are to be read, so you must be careful
>   with the size of the array pointed by str to avoid buffer overflows.

In your case if you do not know the size apriory maybe it is better idea to use `fgets` as it is more secure (though a bit slower).

Comment: These two variables are going to be on the stack, not the heap - their proximity to each other will be determined at compile time (compiling in debug mode might insert padding between them, compiling with optimizations might reorder them...), so it's not something I would call *random*.

Comment: @DCoder I don't quite get you. Once you mention that their position in the stack depends on compilation parameters. I also know that if new variables are introduced they might separate the variables. Random in the context should be read as: "depending on many circumstances, hard to predict deterministically".

Comment: I was just trying to say that the placement is determined at compile time, not runtime, so simply running the program again wouldn't change where the allocations happen.

Comment: @DCoder I never mentioned it will change among several runs of the same program...

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a string of more than 20 `5`s, it overruns the buffer that was allocated to `t` and extends into the buffer that was allocated to `str`.

Then it displays the contents of `str`, which is the string you entered, starting at the 21st character.

Finally, it displays the contents of `t`, but since that string doesn't end with a null character, it continues displaying memory (which is the buffer assiged to `str`) until it encounters the null character after all the `5`s.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid those allocation overlapping issues you can try this alternative, so that the allocation takes place at runtime if I'm not wrong:

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main(void)
    {
      char *str;
      char *t;
      str = new char(100);
      str = (char*)"88888888888888";
      t = new char(20);
      std::cin >> t;
      puts(str);
      puts(t);
      return 0;
    }
```