# C strtok, enter by enter

Tags: c, char, strtok

I want to read the data: sample text opp
I see this: 
sample (enter)
text (enter)
opp (enter)

However, my code does not work well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char separator[] = " ";
    char *schowek;
    char *wejscie;

    gets(&wejscie);
    schowek = strtok(&wejscie,separator);

    while( schowek != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", schowek );
        schowek = strtok( NULL, separator );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Ok,
I have this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char * slowo[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
"eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",
"twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety", "hundred",
"thousand", "million"};
    int liczba[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,1000,1000000};

    char n[]="";
    int i=0;

    char s1[]="zero";


    char separator[] = " ";

    char wejscie[1024];
    if (fgets(wejscie, 1024, stdin))
    {
        char* schowek = strtok(wejscie,separator); /* Removed '&'. */

        if(strcmp(wejscie,n)==0)
        {
            exit;
        }

        while (schowek)
        {
            printf("%s\n", schowek);
            schowek = strtok(NULL, separator);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is everything alright with him?
Now I want to convert string to number.

Sample Input

six
negative seven hundred twenty nine
one million one hundred one

Sample Output

6
-729
1000101

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm almost positive, someone else may need to confirm, but I believe `gets()` is a huge problem. `gets()` will read as many characters are there are until a `\n`, which can read more than the buffer causing problems. I believe it's standard to use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not allocate a buffer to hold the read data.

```
 char *wejscie;
```

Allocates a pointer to hoild the address of your buffer, but not the actual buffer.

```
 gets(&wejscie);
```

reads into that pointer, not into a big enough buffer.

This is the way to do it (allocates the buffer on the stack):

```
 char buffer[1024];
 fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

If you wish to use a pointer and dynamic memory then this is the way to do it:

```
 char * wejscie = malloc(1024);
 fgets(wejscie, 1024, stdin);
```

Comment: Don't encourage use of gets(), it has been removed in C11.

Comment: wasn't aware of that. I'm still in C99

Comment: Do [not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843073/warninggets-function-is-dangerous) [use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-is-dangerous-why-should-not-be-used) gets.

Answer (score 3):

`wejscie` is an unitialised pointer and `gets()` is writing to memory that it should not be, probably causing a segmentation fault. Note that `gets()` is susceptible to buffer overruns as there it provides no facility to limit the number of characters read (see [warning:gets function is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843073/warninggets-function-is-dangerous)). Use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead and a `char[]`:

```
char wejscie[1024];
if (fgets(wejscie, 1024, stdin))
{
    char* schowek = strtok(wejscie,separator); /* Removed '&'. */
    while (schowek)
    {
        printf("%s\n", schowek);
        schowek = strtok(NULL, separator);
    }
}
```

While not relevent to this program, just to note that [`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have memory to store data. Quick example:

```
char wejscie[256];
gets(wejscie);
```

Now `wejscie` is pointing to valid block of memory.

Comment: `wejscie` is the symbol for the buffer address, not `&wejscie` which is the address of that symbol.

Comment: @SergeyL. With arrays: wejscie == &wejscie.

Comment: @Armin: No! `wejscie` and `@wejscie` are different, namely on their type. `(wejscie) + 1 != (@wejscie) + 1`.

Comment: @pmg Back then i didn't realize that :-s, i saw someone with high reputation +50000 saying that they are equal and i believed it without checking.