# Simple String Program in C - Not able to print the string

Tags: c, string

I am not able to print the strings. Need some help on what am I doing wrong and some insight on the best approach in these cases.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void getName(char *name);

int main()
{
    char name[256];
    getName(name);
    printf("Name = %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}

void getName(char *name)
{
    char line[256];
    printf("Please enter your name! \n");
    gets(line);
    name = (char *) malloc(strlen(line));
    strcpy(name, line);
}
```

Comment: You are overriding what you pass a pointer to by what malloc returns and therefore copying to nirvana.... in your case just copy directly to name without malloc

Comment: And please, for the love of unicorns, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` so badly!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what am I doing wrong

Others have already pointed out *some* of the errors, but nobody has shown the **right solution** yet.

Your code is inherently vulnerable to buffer overflows. The `gets()` function doesn't let you specify the buffer size, so if you enter more than 256 characters, this will write out of the bounds of your array. That's bad.

What you should do instead is

1. not use a separate function for this (because it has no benefits in this particular case), and
2. call `fgets()` on your array:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[256];
    fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
    printf("Name = %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, if you ever consider dynamic memory allocation:

1. [Do not cast. It's a deadly sin.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)
2. Check the return value of `malloc()`.
3. You will **still** want to keep track of the buffer size; how about a function like this?

---

```
#define NAME_LENGTH 256

char *getName(void)
{
    char *buf = malloc(NAME_LENGTH);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    fgets(buf, NAME_LENGTH, stdin);
    return buf;
}
```

But, as I mentioned in the comments, in this case you don't need dynamic memory allocation at all.

Comment: When recommending a switch from `gets()` to `fgets()`, it's always a good idea to point out that when `fgets()` reads the entire input line, it doesn't discard the '\n' at the end. Handling the '\n' is trivial, yes, but you have to know it's there first. And you can't expect someone who's still using `gets()` to be aware of the difference without warning them.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do this, comment it out:

```
name = (char *) malloc(strlen(line));
```

You already passed in a buffer for `name`. You don't need to allocate a second buffer.

Also, you didn't add 1 to the allocation to account for the null terminator, but that's not relevant anyway since the allocation is unnecessary either way.

You could `gets` directly into `name` and cut out the `line` middleman, in fact.

Comment: What if I want to dynamically allocate the memory, What should I be doing in that case?

Answer (score 3):

You have over-complicated `getname()` - it just needs to be:

```
void getName(char *name)
{
    printf("Please enter your name! \n");
    gets(name);
}
```

Note that [gets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets) is widely considered to be an [unsafe function to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843073/warninggets-function-is-dangerous), and you should try to get into the habit of using [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Comment: No, it needs to be `fgets(name, size, stdin);` (where `size` is the size of the buffer). The `gets()` function is dangerous and deprecated.

Comment: never use gets(). user fgets() instead. It very insecure. See man gets.

Comment: PaulR Your baby just stepped on a mine field.

Comment: If you want your baby to learn you have to let her make mistakes.

Comment: What if I want to dynamically allocate the memory, What should I be doing in that case?

Comment: @anansharm then `char *line = malloc(SOME_SIZE); fgets(line, SOME_SIZE, stdin);`. But in this case, you don't really need dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Normally you would dynamically allocate in main() and pass the pointer into getname. It would then be up to main to eventually free the pointer when it is no longer needed.

Comment: @H2CO3 I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I know that pointers can be complicated for beginners. So, forget about pointers. How do you expect the following code should run?

```
void change(int a)
{
   a = 10;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    change (a);
    printf("%d", a);  // It prints 20
}
```

(If you did understand the above code, read on. Otherwise, read about functions and scope of a variable.)

Your code has essentially the same structure, only that instead of an int a, you have a char *name. Observe that you have two different **name** identifiers here. One is getName's argument, and the other one is a constant pointer (an array identifier) defined in main. Changing the argument's value of a function doesn't change the value of the callers' parameter.

Comment: However, this is not OP's problem. The problem is that the pointer **is** changed within the function, so `gets()` won't write to the original array but somewhere else.

Comment: Yes it is OP's problem. And the value of a also is changed within the function :)

Comment: It's still not the problem. And I know how functions work, don't teach me C. Read the question instead.

Comment: Oh, the sarcasm. As if I didn't know what's happening and what should be changed to make the program work.

Comment: 1- Understand that I am answering based on your comment, not your knowledge.
2- I am pointing to the important mistakes that OP has made in the provided code using a simple example as an analogy. The example explains why the pointer 'name', allocated dynamically inside getName, cannot be accessed by printf function called in main. It also explains why the array address is not changed to the dynamically allocated memory. These are the main problems in OP's code, I believe. Now you you have 2 options:1-Arguing why they are not OP's problems. 2-Down-vote my answer. Bragging is not one of them.