# Duplicate words and pointers in c

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, duplicates

So i have to make a game/program that looks something like this:

Enter a sentence, Neo: A a Black blACk Cat cAT is in the xirtaM.

Converted sentence: A Black Cat is in the Matrix.

However when I do it, it literally reprints the same A a Black blACk Cat cAT is in the xirtaM. sentence over again I dont think its reading the whole uppercases' in the middle of the word or something. my code is

```
printf ("Enter a sentence, Neo: \n");
gets (str);

// let us convert the string into 2D array
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
        twoD[k][j] = '\0';
        k ++;
        j = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        twoD[k][j] = str[i];
        j ++;
    }
}

twoD[k][j] = '\0';

j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    int present = 0;
    for (l = 1; l < k + 1; l++)
    {
        if (twoD[l][j] == '\0' || l == i)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp (twoD[i], twoD[l]) == 0) {
            twoD[l][j] = '\0';
            present = present + 1;
        }
    }
    // if (present > 0)      | uncomment this `if` block if you
    // {                 | want to remove all the occurrences 
    //  twoD[i][j] = '\0';   | of the words including the word
    // }                 | itself.
}

j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < k + 1; i++)
{
    if (twoD[i][j] == '\0')
        continue;
    else
        printf ("%s ", twoD[i]);
}

printf ("\n");
return 0;
```

Comment: where's the part where your program fixes the uppercase?

Comment: provide little more info on what is the general rule it supposed to work, in the example some words are repeated and some are not, is always first three or can vary etc?

Comment: by the way you should avoid [gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843073/warninggets-function-is-dangerous#:~:text=As%20Wikipedia%27s%20article%20says%2C%20gets%20%28%29%20is%20inherently,allocated%20to%20that%20char%20%2A%20in%20any%20situation.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simple. The `strcmp()` function in C is case sensitive. So the function will treat the words differently.

Run your `str` contents through `tolower()` or something like that to make everything lower case.

```c
.
.
gets(str);
for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
.
.
.
```

Then it should be working.

Comment: Getting a compiling error  gets (str);
 for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)str[i]=tolower(str[i]);}
 it works if i remove the for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)str[i]=tolower(str[i]);} line

Comment: You might have to include string.h and compile in C99 mode.

Comment: @ibosalaj I tested it with your code in my system so it's good